# Storing Private Key for scp into Jar

Tags: java, jar, scp, private-key

I need to update this class to make it retrieve the public key file (keyfile) from within the Jar I'm currently running.

For now the private-key file is in the same directory as the Jar, it's specified into a properties and passed by variable keyfile.

```
public static void download(String username, String keyfile, String ipAddress, String absoluteFileName, String destinationPath){

    Scp scpTask = createScpTask(22);
    scpTask.setKeyfile(keyfile);
    String passphrase = "";
    scpTask.setPassphrase(passphrase);
    scpTask.setFile(username + "@" + ipAddress+ ":" + absoluteFileName);
    scpTask.setTodir(destinationPath);
    scpTask.setTrust(true);
    scpTask.execute();

}
```

Have you got any idea?

Many thanks
--Alessandro

Comment: put it into the ressources and fetch it with: `this.getClass().getResource(<filename>);`

Comment: maybe you use another folder for the ressources (but its similar to the src-folder in eclipse)

Comment: I can't use "this", because it's a static class..

Comment: use another object. for example `Integer.class.getResource(name)`